# I cant get a .jar file to actually open

Tags: jar

I've downloaded a .jar file but when I try to open it, it opens but, literally, NOTHING happens, I have java downloaded, 13-inch mac pro latest version Ventura 13.2.1, Ive tried compressing it, but obviously that doesn't work, and nothing else works either, i can get other .jar files to open, but not this

Comment: what do you expect to happen? what jar is it?

Comment: The file name? the file name is "Wurst-Client-v7.32-MC1.19.4.jar

Comment: and I have no clue what is supposed to happen

Comment: so it could be that it is working correctly :) try to run `java -jar Wurst-Client-v7.32-MC1.19.4.jar` from a terminal and see what error it shows

Comment: what do you mean terminal

Comment: from the app? okay

Comment: it was unable to access it

Comment: unable to access the jar file

Comment: RASCIO RASCIO RASCIO HELP ME